# Does NRVO also apply to coroutines?

Tags: c++, optimization, standards, c++20, c++-coroutine

In the following example, *NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization)* applies as per [this article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/11/28/return-value-optimizations/):

```
std::string f1()
{
    std::string str;

    return str; // NVRO applies here!
}
```

However, consider:

```
task<std::string> f2()
{
    std::string str;

    co_return str; // Does NVRO also apply here?
}
```

Comment: "*NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization) is guaranteed as per this article:*" The article says no such thing.

Comment: Do note that in your article NRVO is not guaranteed.  It even has *Note though that compilers have different optimization capabilities, and there is no guarantee that the above optimizations will be applied* right after the NRVO example code.

Comment: I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NRVO as defined by the article you linked (i.e. not even creating a temporary) isn't a thing for coroutines because [how `co_return` works](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/stmt.return.coroutine#2) is up to the user-provided coroutine promise type: the expression in the `co_return` statement is fed to the promise's `return_value` method, which can decide what to do with it.

However there is a related optimization that still may be useful. [[class.copy.elision]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.copy.elision#3) says the following:

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a non-volatile object or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type. In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation is first considered before attempting a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a return ([stmt.return]) or co_­return ([stmt.return.coroutine]) statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an implicitly movable entity declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or
> - [...]
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy or the `return_­value` overload to call is first performed as if the expression or operand were an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, overload resolution is performed again, considering the expression or operand as an lvalue.

This means that if you return a local variable by name from a coroutine it will be moved, not copied (as long as the promise type supports this). For example, clang accepts the following despite the fact that it's not possible to copy a `std::unique_ptr<int>`:

```cpp
// Assume a coroutine task type called Task<T> whose associated promise has a
// return_value(T) method. The co_return here will successfully call that
// method.
Task<std::unique_ptr<int>> MakeInt() {
  auto result = std::make_unique<int>(17);
  co_return result;
}
```

So the optimization "value is fed to coroutine promise as an rvalue reference even though `std::move` wasn't used" does apply. But the standard doesn't say "move constructor isn't even called", and it can't because it's up to the promise what to do with the expression it's given.

Comment: I'm not sure if this draft applies to C++20. Then again, there have been so many defect reports against C++20 that I can't be sure what "C++20" even is.

Comment: C++20 is [approximately the same as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links) N4861 and N4868. I chose N4868 because it has a nice HTML version online. The answer is very unlikely to be any different looking at the actual standard (which isn't publicly available).

Comment: I brought that up because I looked at N4861; it's what I use by default for "C++20". And [it doesn't have that line.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.elision#1.1) It only talks about `return`s, not `co_return`s.

Comment: Oh I see. I think you're looking at the wrong part. [Paragraph 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.elision#3) is there in N4861 too.

Comment: That's about implicit movement from return values, not copy elision. NRVO refers to what paragraph 1.1 is talking about (returning named automatic variables in a function).

Comment: Did you read my answer? I cover the distinction between the two. The standard doesn't use the term NRVO and the question wasn't clear what the user wanted. It's true that you don't get guaranteed copy elision, but you do get a useful property that is often grouped into the NRVO umbrella.

Comment: "*The standard doesn't use the term NRVO and the question wasn't clear what the user wanted.*" Nonsense. The term is common C++ vernacular, and it has a well-understood meaning. An answer should attempt to translate the vernacular concept into the actual standardese that brought it forth.

Comment: Okay that's fair, thanks. I updated the answer to lead with "NRVO as defined by that article doesn't apply". The other form of copy-elision is still useful, and is actually what I was looking for myself when I found this question. Your answer misled me temporarily because I read it to imply the other form of copy elision doesn't work. I think it's wrong to say "`co_return` values are never subject to copy elision" when the copy elision section of the standard specifically addresses `co_return`. (Your answer was still far more helpful than the top-rated answer though, so thanks for that.)

Answer (score 6):

> I know that NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization) is mandatory since C++17:

It is not. NRVO is still an optimisation.

The non-named Return Value Optimisation (RVO) is mandatory.

> ```
> // Is NVRO also guaranteed here?
> ```

No, because NRVO is never guaranteed.

Comment: @xmllmx Pay attention to the lack of "Named" in that quote. Also see the examples, none of which return an lvalue. Also see the section "Non-mandatory elision of copy", which mentions NRVO in particular.

Comment: Why is`return str;` `NVRO` while `co_return str;` isn't?

Comment: What do you mean by "`co_return str;` isn't [NRVO]"?

Comment: Is `co_return str;` guaranteed to **move** rather than **copy** the `str` to the final result in the concrete example?

Comment: @xmllmx I didn't check the standard, but according to cppreference yes, `str` would be moved. This has nothing to do with copy elision or NRVO however.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, guaranteed elision in C++17 only applies to returning a prvalue from a function directly. Returning a named variable is only subject to elision if the compiler feels like it.

As for the meat of your question, `co_return` values are *never* subject to copy elision, guaranteed or otherwise. Elision for return values keys off of the `return` keyword, and coroutines aren't allowed to use `return`. They use `co_return`, which the [elision logic in the standard doesn't key off of](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision). So elision does not apply.

The reason why this was done is because of how coroutines work. A coroutine is a function that has a promise object in it. This promise object is how you shepard the coroutine's `co_return` value (and other state) to the "future" object that the coroutine function returned.

Elision works in normal functions because calling conventions require the caller to pass the storage for a return value to the function. So the function's implementation can choose to just build the object in that storage rather than building a separate stack object and copying into it upon `return`.

In a coroutine, the return value lives inside the promise, so that can't really happen.

Comment: Note that [class.copy.elision] (the section you quoted) _does_ have something to say about coroutines; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72513585/1505451). It doesn't allow omitting the move constructor call, but it does provide for not making a copy.

Answer (score -1):

Just because answer looks too long. The standard says that the statement `co_return <expr>;` is equivalent to:

```
P.return_value(<expr>);
```

where `P` is the coroutine's promise object. From that I suppose you can answer this question and many other questions.

If you are looking for coroutine documentation look here:

- [dcl.fct.def.coroutine](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.coroutine)
- [stmt.return.coroutine](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return.coroutine)
- [expr.await](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.await)
- [expr.yield](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.yield)
- [support.coroutine](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/support.coroutine)