Is there any guarantees on where the coroutine C++ return object is stored?
Let the following be a coroutine:
ReturnType foo(Args args)

And the following calling scenario:
void caller() {
   ReturnType ret = foo(...);
}

To my understanding after calling the coroutine foo:

coroutine activation frame is constructed (::new is used if
necessary)
promise_type is constructed in the activation frame, let's say the following is called: promise_type promise{...};
promise.get_return_object() is called.
then there is a call to co_await promise.initial_suspend().
Now there are two options: foo() is suspended or not

If foo is suspended, is there now a return statement to of retun_object back to caller? Possibly there is a Return Value Optimization?
If foo is not suspended, I imagine that coroutine needs to store the return_object on the coroutine activation frame, possibly on the stack or heap part of the coroutine activation frame then at first point of suspension or co_return, there is a return return_object statement that returns the object back to caller. Am I right?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61870627/4342498

the return_object is not in the coroutine frame, because it is returned to the caller at first suspension (on promise.initial_suspend(), or co_await or co_yield in the body of the function, or promise.final_suspend()). Note that if there is no suspension, the coroutine is like a simple function deleting at the end the coroutine frame and returning the return_object. So the return_objet can (must?) be returned by Return L-Value Optimisation.


If foo is suspended, is there now a return statement to of retun_object back to caller?

There doesn't need to be. The call to get_return_object already filled in the caller's return value. If the coroutine needed to store the return object (or more likely, store the actual return value, with the value given to the caller pointing to it), then it has the opportunity to do so in get_return_object. That's what this function is for.
As with any function's return value, it lives on the caller's stack, not the function itself.

Yes, but I imagine the return value can only be written to caller at suspension point or after co_return. Unless of course RVO is performed.  Which per @NathanOliver comment is clearly not guaranteed.

@dwto: "I imagine the return value can only be written to caller at suspension point or after co_return." Based on what do you say this? The memory for the return value object for a function is always provided by the caller. RVO simply means that the function body will modify that memory instead of copying into it in the return statement. But the memory is always there, and the implementation can write to it whenever it wants.

@dwto: Note that co_return does not (directly) affect the return value object. That's why it's a different keyword from return. All co_return does is tell the promise "here's a value" and then jumps to the final suspension point of the coroutine.
